# Fürs vs Für's - Ist es das Gleiche?

Tags: spelling

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "Fürs" und "Für's".
Bis jetzt habe ich immer geschrieben "Danke für's Richten", aber habe erst kürzlich gelesen, dass man, wenn man es vor einem substantiviertem Verb schreibt, es ohne Apostroph schreibt, also "Danke fürs Richten".

Wann schreibt man es nun ohne, und wann mit Apostroph?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nach aktuellen Regeln ist nur "fürs" korrekt und "für's" ist falsch. Wenn man eine Präposition mit einem Artikel verschmelzt, dann wird kein Apostroph gesetzt.

[Rechtschreibregeln](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/apostroph#K13):

> D 14:
>
> In den folgenden Fällen wird üblicherweise kein Apostroph gesetzt:
>
> 1. bei den allgemein üblichen Verschmelzungen von Präposition (Verhältniswort) und Artikel;
>
>    **ans, aufs, durchs, fürs, hinters, ins, übers, unters, vors**
>
>    am, beim, hinterm, überm, unterm, vorm
>
>    hintern, übern, untern, vorn; zur

Auch ein kurzer Text auf der Wikipedia-Seite zu [Diskussion über fehlerhafte Verwendung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostroph#Diskussion_%C3%BCber_fehlerhafte_Verwendung).

Comment: Auf der angegebenen Wikipedia-Seite habe ich keinen Eintrag für "für's" gefunden. Also schreibt man es überhaupt nicht mehr?

Comment: Meines Wissens war "für's" auch nie korrekt. Aber ich kann mich täuschen.

Comment: Schreib es bitte in deine Antwort, damit es andere sofort lesen, dass für's nie richtig ist, und man nur noch fürs schreibt.

Comment: @Eller Du täuscht dich nicht. Es war noch nie richtig.